# Trying to update url-parameter with onClick in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to setup a url that changes depending on the useState. I'm doing this because I want to be able to access both states with the url. So this is what my router file looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";


function router(){
    return (
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/restaurant/:toggleParameter" children={<Restaurant/>}/>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        );
    }


export default router;
```

An the component Restaurant looks like this:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {useParams,Redirect} from "react-router-dom";
function RestaurantLandingPage(){


    const {toggleParameter} = useParams();
    console.log("Parameter");
    console.log(toggleParameter);

    const [profileToggle,setProfileToggle] = useState(toggleParameter);

    const restaurantID =localStorage.getItem("restaurantId");
    console.log(restaurantID);

    const changeParameterToProfile =()=>{
        setProfileToggle("profile");
    };

    const changeParameterToMenu=()=>{
        setProfileToggle("menu");
    }
        return (
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div className="restaurantHover">
                    <button
                        className="switchButton"
                        onClick={()=>{changeParameterToProfile()}}
                        style={profileToggle==="profile"? {textDecoration:'underline',textDecorationThickness:'3px',textDecorationColor:'#6C5AF2'}:{}}
                    >
                        Profile
                    </button>
                    <button
                        className="switchButton"
                        onClick={changeParameterToMenu}
                        style={profileToggle==="menu"?{textDecoration:'underline',textDecorationThickness:'3px',textDecorationColor:'#6C5AF2'}:{}}
                    >
                        Menu
                    </button>
                    <div id="switchBottom"/>
                    {(profileToggle==="profile")&&(
                        <Contact profileToggle={profileToggle} changeParameterToMenu={changeParameterToMenu}/>
                    )}
                    {(profileToggle==="menu")&&(
                        <RestauarntMenuOverview/>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        )}
}
export default RestaurantLandingPage;
```

The url-param "toggleParameter" is "profile" or "menu". I'll access it with useParams(). Now if I press the button Profile the url-param "toggleParameter" should switch to Profile and if I press the button Menu the url-param "toggleParameter" should switch to Menu. I thought I could use Redirect like this:

```
<button
className="switchButton"
onClick={()=>{changeParameterToProfile();
<Redirect to={/restaurant/{profileToggle}/>}}
style={profileToggle==="profile"? {textDecoration:'underline',textDecorationThickness:'3px',textDecorationColor:'#6C5AF2'}:{}}>
Profile
</button>
```

But this doesn't work. I'm a little bit confused with all the react-router possibilities because I haven't found the right one yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React doesn't allow updating the state when the component is unmounted & it will cause some serious memory leak hidden before your eyes. Also `setState` function is an Asynchrounus function & it can get called after the `history.push` method. Changing the route with `history.push` will unmount the component & in some cases `setState` might get called afterwards causing state update on unmounted component. Also the value of `profileToggle` will only get changed after `setProfileToggle` is called keeping the value of `profileToggle` same & `history.push` will also use the previous value & you or the user have to click the button twice to go to `/restaurant/profile` or `/restaurant/menu`

**Code**:

```
import {useParams,useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
function RestaurantLandingPage(){
   const history = useHistory()
   const {toggleParameter} = useParams(); 

  const changeParameterToProfile =()=>{
        history.push(`/restaurant/profile`)
    };

    const changeParameterToMenu=()=>{
        history.push(`/restaurant/menu`)
    }

  return(
        ...... 
        <button
         className="switchButton"
         onClick={()=>changeParameterToProfile()}
         style={toggleParameter==="profile"? 
                 { textDecoration:'underline',
                   textDecorationThickness:'3px',
                   textDecorationColor:'#6C5AF2'
                 }:{}
                }
         >
          Profile
        </button>
    ...... 
    ) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import {useParams,useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
function RestaurantLandingPage(){
   const history = useHistory()
   const {toggleParameter} = useParams(); 

  const changeParameterToProfile =()=>{
        setProfileToggle("profile");
        history.push(`/restaurant/${profileToggle} `)
    };

    const changeParameterToMenu=()=>{
        setProfileToggle("menu")
        history.push(`/restaurant/${profileToggle} `)
    }

  return(
        ...... 
        <button
         className="switchButton"
         onClick={()=>{changeParameterToProfile();}
         style={profileToggle==="profile"? {textDecoration:'underline',textDecorationThickness:'3px',textDecorationColor:'#6 
    C5AF2'}:{}}>
    Profile
    </button>
     <button
      className="switchButton"
     onClick={()=>{changeParameterToMenu();}
         style={profileToggle==="profile"? 
{textDecoration:'underline',textDecorationThickness:'3px',textDecorationColor:'#6 
     C5AF2'}:{}}>
     Menu
     </button>
    ...... 
    ) 
}
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: this won't work either as the state of `profileToggle` will remain same until the function executes & also `setState ` is asynchronus thus the callback to set the state might get called afterwards thus there will be a state update on a unmounted component which is a React-OP. React will complain about this in the console...  Thus instead of using a separate state for the dynamic part of the url use just the hard coded `profile` or `menu` value to change routes.. See below:

Comment: Have you tried it and it didn't work! Try it if it didn't work tell me, here you are just complicating your code `react-router-dom` is easy to use and to implement try that one first then you conclude.

Comment: @Cirspen Gari It's not about how easy a library is, its about how the library works. Your solution should work but there will be some bugs later on. So I just pointed out those. I'm just suggesting & its not my problem. I didn't asked the question, right?

Comment: @CrispenGari thank you for your answer! I used KR Tirtho's solution but thank you anyway!

Comment: Okay enjoy coding buddy